# Failed with code 405 when using axios to make a call to controller api in asp.net core react application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, controller, axios

I am working on a simple react + asp.net core application where I want to simply add records to the database (created using entityframework core). There is a very simple form with just a textbox and a button. When clicking the button, I receive the following error:

> Error: Request failed with status code 405

I did debugging in runtime, and the Create method in the controller class is not evoked. That is, somehow the axios does not recognize the url provided. Below is the client side code:

```
class Form extends Component {

    state = { rubricName: '' }

    handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();           

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/Rubric/Create',
            data: {
                title: this.state.rubricName,
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Here is the controller api class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class RubricController : Controller
{
    RubricDataAccessLayer objRubric = new RubricDataAccessLayer();


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Rubric/Create")]
    public int Create(string title)
    {
        return objRubric.AddRubric(new Rubric { Title = title });
    }
}
```

Any ideas about why I am having this error?

Comment: It sounds like it might be a CORS issue - is it an `OPTIONS` request that's actually being sent and getting that `405`? With `[Route(...)]` commented-out, the endpoint would be just `api/Rubric`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks for the comment! I have uncommented `[Route()]` also set `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`. Still no luck... Any further ideas?

Comment: @renakre If you have both `Route` attribute the resulting url is following `api/Rubric/api/Rubric/Create`.

Comment: @Alexander that is correct, thanks a lot! would you like to post this as an answer so that I can mark?

Comment: You need to enable [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2) at the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified incorrect url in request. If there is only one `Route` attribute on controller the url should be

```
api/Rubric
```

If you keep both urls the resulting url is combined value of `Route` attributes

```
api/Rubric/api/Rubric/Create
```

If you want to override action url without combining it with controller one just add leading `/` (or `~/`)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/Rubric/Create")]
public int Create(string title)
```

In this case request url should be

```
api/Rubric/Create
```